# write a function that removes first occurence of a string

Tags: python

I want to Write a function `remove` which takes a list (`word`) and a string (`words`). Your function should remove the ﬁrst occurence of `word` in `words`. If `word` does not occur at all in `words`, the function should simply leave `words` unchanged.

I have tried

```
def remove (item):
    try:    
        words.remove('')
    except ValueError: 
        pass
    return words
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close. You need to replace your `''` literal with `item` and add a `words` parameter. As is, it tries to remove an empty word from the global variable `words`, and it does that just fine. You, however, probably want it to remove `item` from a passed `words`.

Also, the indentation's messed up (all the lines except the first need to be indented a little bit more) but I'm guessing that wasn't how your original code was.

Comment: Also, return the result of the call, since `words` is a string. (I'm not sure the OP is that close. Or why `word` is a list, maybe they're supposed to be the other way around.)

Comment: @millimoose: I'm guessing it was accidentally swapped in the question, and if it's a list, it can be mutated in place without needing to be returned. I don't know if they're that close either any more, but we've received no response from them, so it might not matter in any case.